# Identifying multiple parts of an image through an NN

Tags: neural-networks

I am looking into a way of identify and classify multiple parts of an image, i.e. if there is a picture of a woman drinking a coke, it would highlight the woman as a woman and then it would highlight the can of coke as a can.

My initial thought was to do this by making an output tensor instead of a simple vector. Said in another way, when normal NN's classify an image, it is basically outputting a 1 someone in a vector of 0s. My idea was instead to create a matrix for each classification and then for every part of the picture it would put a 1 in the matrix output and a 0 everywhere else. The can would have a different dimension, but would be categorized by a 1 in the part of the picture where the can is and 0 elsewhere.

I have tried a variation of this on the MNIST dataset, instead of using 10 matrices stack ontop of each other, I instead made a vector which was 28*28*10 long as my output vector. The first 28*28 instances represented 0 the next 28*28 represented 1 and so forth.

While this neural net actually does learn it does so EXTREMELY slow, and I have not yet managed to train it to make any meaningful prediction at all.

Has this approach been tried before? I have tried to research about it, but was unable to find anything.

If anyone can tell me why this won't work I'd very much like to hear it. It just seems to me that when we only classify an entire image as something then we are throwing away A LOT of information. To give an example, if you want to show a kid what a tiger looks like you don't show him/her ten pictures with a tiger in it and 10 pictures without, and say the first ten has a tiger in it, now can you figure out what a tiger looks like? Instead you show them specifically what in the picture is a tiger.

This may sound confusing, but I am a little bit at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at image segmentation algos.

Search for Unet or Fully Convolutional Neural Network. Basically what it does is doing classification for every pixel. The only problem you might have is that you have no labelled data...

Comment: I mean you'd have to label the data by basically "shading" the figures and classify them right?

Comment: you need to label every pixel in your image. so if you do not have these labels then this might be an awful lot of work. if you have them you can apply softmax classification to every pixel.